# Which umask is more secure in Linux ( 022 or 027)?

Tags: linux, security, unix, shell, umask

Is there any security concerns if the umask is set to 027 for root (Basically I want to know if 027 is better in security than 022 ) ?

As per my understanding 027 is a better one from security perspective . But I want to confirm this point .

Answer (score 2):

027 is better from security perspective.

Even better is to use 077 for root.

With 027 mask, when root creates a file, it can be read and executed by users who belongs to the group of the file.

With 077 mask, only root can read write and execute files.

Why is 077 better?

- because by making files belonging to user readeable by root only, it avoids some common system administrator mistakes.
- because it's harder for an attacker to run privilege escalation only poorly written shell scripts/binaries if they can't even read it.

Comment: Yes, 077 is more secure, but also more likely to break things (e.g. when access is allowed via groups like with nginx + php-fpm). So 027 is said to be best for security + usability. 
But 077 wasn't even asked for in the question.